# Accessing Object properties in Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am attempting to build an XML string using Linq to XML. a is an `IList<Object>`, making x an `Object`. Each object is comprised of two properties, DisplayName and ID. I'm not sure how to reference those specific properties.

The below code runs but an exception is thrown "unable to cast object of type 'system.object[]' to type 'system.collections.arraylist'."

How do I access the properties of x?

```
XDocument InstancePickerUserResponse =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("Values",
            new XAttribute("Count", a.Count),
            a.Select(x =>
                new XElement("Value",
                    new XAttribute("DisplayName", ((ArrayList)x)[1]),
                    new XAttribute("Id", ((ArrayList)x)[0])
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

I should note that if I use the below foreach loop, I'm able to access the properties of x. This is because I'm casting x as an object array instead of an object.

```
foreach (object[] x in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(x[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the `ArrayList` cast, it is not clear why it is even there.

Comment: That was my first try, to just use x[0] and x[1]. That does not compile stating "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'". I'll add some clarification at the end.

Comment: Sounds like you need to cast to `object[]` then.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that within Linq to XML. If I try to cast the entire list ahead of time, it fails saying unable to cast.

Comment: In your first example replace you cast to `ArrayList` which x isn't, with a cast to `object[]` which apparently x is.

Comment: doh! That was a silly oversight on my part. That did the trick. Post as answer and I will mark.